# Can't connect textfield from subview

Tags: ios, swift

I have this subview `Meal Form View` and I want to connect the Text Fields for being able to save the info. How could I connect?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create `IBOutlet`s in the class of `Meal Form View` for those text fields.
After that, you will be able to access the text fields in ViewController thru the `Meal Form View`s outlet `mealFormView`.

MealFormView:

```
class MealFormView: UIView {
  @IBOutlet weak var caloriesTextView: UITextField!
}
```

View Controller:

```
class DietViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var mealFormView: MealFormView!

  func someFuction() {
    let calories = mealFormView.caloriesTextField.text
  }
}
```